# How to debug .net dll assemblies in staging server

Tags: .net, debugging, dll, assemblies

Is there a way or tool by which I can debug .net dll assemblies in staging server. I have a ASP.NET web dlls deployed on staging server.

Updates

1. Implementing debugging logic within code to turn off/on debugging. (from @maple_shaft)
2. ASP.NET Remote debugging. (from @maple_shaft)

Question:

1. Is there a trace option in ASP.NET which can be turned off/on on *.config file, allows display of every class is running, like *.ASPX trace function.

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to put logging code throughout your code so that you can switch to the debug level in your logging configuration.

Apart from this true debugging can be done remotely using Visual Studio, however there are some prerequisites:

1) Your assemblies deployed to staging must be built in Debug mode.

2) You must have the appropriate firewall exceptions for the remote debugging ports open on the staging server.

Your app deployed on staging is probably built in Release mode, making it impossible to do remotely, however you can always build a deployment in Debug mode and manually redeploy to your server to do this.

As far as firewall exceptions go, you will have to go through the right channels in your organization to get firewall exceptions made for you if they are needed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will consider your options. One more question, is there a trace option in ASP.NET which can be turned off/on on *.config file, allows display of every class is running, like *.ASPX trace function.

Comment: I know of Trace logging that can be turned on from a config file for measuring performance, but I cannot think of such a trace option out of box.  That does not mean that such a thing doesn't exist, I just don't know.  Perhaps you should consider asking that as a seperate question and you may get a good response.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out WinDbg (part of Debugging Tools for Windows, which is now part of Windows SDK)?

I don't have as much experience with debugging .NET apps in release environment, but we had few extreme cases where a problem in native code would only occur on customer machines and couldn't be duplicated anywhere else.  Placing WinDbg, along with few needed source files and debug symbols, allowed us to solve those issues directly in customer environment.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will have a look at it.